# Can i change audio/video sync in a stream generated by ffmpeg, while it runs?

Tags: ffmpeg, zeromq

i am trying this:

```
ffmpeg -v verbose -re -y -i syncTest.mp4 -af azmq,volume=1 \ 
-c:v copy -c:a aac ./output.mp4
```

then invoke

```
echo 'Parsed_volume_1 volume 0' | ./zmqsend
```

it works, audio is muted until i invoke it again with 1

but,

```
ffmpeg -v verbose -re -y -i syncTest.mp4 -af \ 
azmq,adelay=delays=0S:all=1 -c:v copy -c:a aac ./output.mp4
```

and then doing something like

```
echo Parsed_adelay_1 delays 20000S | ./zmqsend
echo Parsed_adelay_1 all 1 | ./zmqsend
```

does not work, it prints:

78 Function not implemented

is there totally no way to do it?

Comment: The filter has to support commands - adelay doesn't.

Comment: Thank you, but maybe there is an alernative way to get it done with ffmpeg?